# Double every value in the array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, indexing

Hi I wrote a code that supposed to double every value in the array. For unknown reason it doesn't display horizontal instead it displays vertical, and it combines the original number with the new double values how do I split them from the each other and display them horizontally. I be very thank full if you could help me.

```
 int[] A = { -2, 5, -1, 9, -6, 23, 67, 1, -8, 7, -3, 90 };

 Console.WriteLine("\n=====================\n");
 Changes(A); //<<< original index value
 Console.WriteLine("\nEvery Value gets doubled");

 Changes(A); //<<< new changes
```

The `Changes()` method:

```
static void Changes(int[] array) //<<<<<<<< methods
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n=====================\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", array[i]); //<<< display orgininal value
        array[i] *= 2;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", array[i]); // <<new value
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n=====================\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` will show the output vertically

try this instead

```
        Console.Write("{0} ", array[i]); //<<< display orgininal value
        array[i] *= 2;
         //here I use = to  separate the output put you can use any other string you want 
        Console.Write(" = {0}", array[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Console.Write()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`

Answer (score 1):

in case like this I always used to use String.Join() method.

```
int[] A = { -2, 5, -1, 9, -6, 23, 67, 1, -8, 7, -3, 90 };

Console.WriteLine("\n=====================\n");
Changes(A); //<<< original index value
Console.WriteLine("\nEvery Value gets doubled");

Changes(A); //<<< new changes


static void Changes(int[] array) //<<<<<<<< methods
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n=====================\n");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", String.Join(", ", array)); //<<< display orgininal values

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
      array[i] *= 2;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", String.Join(", ", array)); // <<new values
    Console.WriteLine("\n=====================\n");
}
```

Comment: String.Join() is new to me since im new to coding I wont use it yet :B

Comment: The type string comes with many useful methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Fell free to use them to learn good practises.

Comment: Do you know a way to let the user change the value of 
any element in the array?

Comment: Sure, see the example with dinosaurs, and use of Array.FindIndex method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhdxx3we%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

You can change all your code for this ;)

```
int i = -1;
A.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\n=====================\nOriginal value: {0}\nNew value: {1}\n=====================\n", x, A[++i] *= 2)));
```

=====================

Original value: -2

New value: -4

=====================

And so on.....

Comment: That doesn't actually change the values.

Comment: Now it does... I thought that only needed to show the new values. Now it update the values and in only 1 line, show the old one and change to the new one